# VBA: If then with 2 statements after then

Tags: excel, vba

How can I write an if then statement where if something is true then 2 actions will be completed? For example:

```
Sub button()

If Range("B17").Value = 1 Then
Range("C3:F3") = Range("C21:F21").Value And 
Range("C10:F10") = Range("C22:F22").Value

Else

...

End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that the downvotes are really warranted. The question would strike any experienced programmer as odd, but if you are just starting out, it is a somewhat natural mistake. "And" has multiple meanings in natural language, one of which is to describe sequencing of actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBA `And` is a [logical connective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) in which `A And B` evaluates to `True` if and only if `A` and `B` are both `True`. It isn't a form of punctuation in which says "do A and then do B". You can just drop the `And`:

```
If Range("B17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("C3:F3") = Range("C21:F21").Value
    Range("C10:F10") = Range("C22:F22").Value
Else

    ...

End If
```

is unproblematic.

Also, note that the `Else` clause is optional in VBA. If all you want is for two actions to take place if some condition is true and you don't have alternative actions for when it is false, you can just skip the `Else` part entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub button()

    'First declare your workbook & worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Range("B17").Value = 1 Then
            .Range("C3:F3").Value = .Range("C21:F21").Value
            .Range("C10:F10").Value = .Range("C22:F22").Value
        Else

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```